# onCenterChange callback returns undefined @react-google-maps/api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

I have been using a library called `@react-google-maps/api` and I want to store the map center as react state and I want the user to be able to drag the map while the marker always stays at the center of the map (**uber style** location selection)

The Problem is when I call the `onCenterChange` of the  component, it returns me undefined

and when after store the `map` instance (recieved on the `onLoad` callback) as react state. The map instance returns the exact same center everytime (I guess the state save is static)

```
<GoogleMap
        id={id}
        zoom={zoom}
        center={center}
        options={options}
        mapContainerStyle={{ width, height }}
        onLoad={m => {
          if (!map) setMap(m);
        }}
        onCenterChanged={e => {
          console.log(map);
          if (map) {
            console.log(parseCoords(map.getCenter()));
          }
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </GoogleMap>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, `onCenterChanged` event does not accept any arguments in [`@react-google-maps/api`](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api):

```
onCenterChanged?: () => void;
```

Instead map instance could be retrieved via `onLoad` event handler and map center saved in state like this:

```
function Map(props) {
  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({
    lat: -25.0270548,
    lng: 115.1824598
  });

  function handleLoad(map) {
    mapRef.current = map;
  }

  function handleCenterChanged() {
    if (!mapRef.current) return;
    const newPos = mapRef.current.getCenter().toJSON();
    setPosition(newPos);
  }

  return (
    <GoogleMap
      onLoad={handleLoad}
      onCenterChanged={handleCenterChanged}
      zoom={props.zoom}
      center={props.center}
      id="map"
    >
    </GoogleMap>
  );
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fwxm1i) which demonstrates how to keep the marker centered of the map while dragging the map.